# How to get the full url from a sharepoint workflow using c #

Tags: c#, sharepoint, httpcontext

I have a custom workflow associated with a list sharepoint 2010 using c#. This workflow is executed when you create a new item in the list and depending on the value of the url is the code that I run. My question. How I can get the full url from a sharepoint workflow?

I use:

```
var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
```

Result: Error, the object is null or is not an instance

Comment: Can you provide more source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [SPWorkflowActivationProperties.WebUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowactivationproperties.weburl.aspx)

Comment: thanks for responding, but I tried it returns the relative path and absolute path need,
example: http://sitesharepoint/List/myList/AllItems.aspx?id=5 , I need to get id=5

Comment: And SPWorkflowActivationProperties.ItemId property for the item id

Comment: This id is a custom parameter I pass the url, not the id of the list. I need to get the full url from workflow. I've tried everything but nothing I find. Plaese help me.

Comment: I think, the best way is to register your parameter in properties of item. After, in your workflows you have just to retreive it. Be carefull with id parameter, because au SharePoint protected parameter too.

Comment: I need to get the absolute url showed in the browser inside the workflow. How can I do it?

Comment: I think you can't because you are outside http context. Workflow is a service.